# Rails 4 jquery highlight effect not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to highlight changes in my posts index page where the form is also displayed and submit(both on same page). I'd like to slide and highlight the new post. to know if post==new I put current_item in my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|  
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to posts_path, notice: '<i class="fa fa-check fa-5x"></i>'.html_safe }
        format.js   { @current_item = @post } #use this in vew to check if post is newly added
        format.json { render action: 'index', status: :created, location: @post }

      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<% if post == @current_item %>
            <div id="current_item">
              <% end %>

     ..........more code......

 <% if post == @current_item %>
            </div>
              <% end %>
```

my js

```
 $(function() {
  $('#current_item').effect('highlight', {}, 3000)
   });
```

nothing happens, and I'm also trying to do the slide down effect on that div as well bu want to get the highlight working first.

I tried doing it with css with no success. it highlights everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect is **not** part of the core jQuery library. It is part of jQuery UI library. Did you include that in your project?
Source: [api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/)

Here is a working example:

```
$(function() 
{
    $('#current_item').effect('highlight', {}, 3000)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s8ubK/

So, I guess you forgot to include the jQuery UI library in your project.

Comment: //=require jquery.ui.all in my application.js and using the jquery-ui-rails gem could it be in the controller? @current_item part, is it right?

Comment: Is there a div in your page source with the ID current_item? Then it's not the controller. Can you open the console of your webbrowser (Cmd/Ctrl + i in Chrome), then go to console and enter this: `$.ui.version`. If it returns something, jQuery UI is loaded. If not then that's your problem. Did you also include the CSS file for jQuery UI?

Comment: ui is loaded, Crtl+Shift+j for chrome console

Comment: Ok. Did you confirm the element exist in the HTML source?

Comment: Do you have multiple tags with the same ID? Could you try to disable Turbolinks if you use it: http://blog.flightswithfriends.com/post/53943440505/how-to-disable-turbolinks-in-rails-4

Comment: no I do not, is there another way to pass the value to the view of current_item?